# How to use regex to replace these words?

Tags: php, regex

From:

```
citys["bj"] = {bj:"Beijing"};
citys["han"] = {haikou:"Haikou",hainan:"Hainan",sanya:"Sanya",wzs:"Wuzhishan"};
```

To:

```
"bj" => array("bj"=>"Beijing");
"han" => array("haikou"=>"Haikou","hainan"=>"Hainan","sanya"=>"Sanya","wzs"=>"Wuzhishan");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Updated:  I hope to solve this in one step by regex.

Comment: Did you try something and can you post it?

Comment: Any reason to solve this specifically with regex?

Comment: I want to know how to solve this by regex in one step and I'm sorry the example probably make misunderstanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this in two steps:

```
$temp = preg_replace('/(\w*?):("\w*?")/', '"$1"=>$2', $input);
$output = preg_replace('/citys\[("\w*?")\]\s*=\s*\{(.*?)\}/', '$1 => array($2)', $temp);
```

First you transform all `haikou:"Haikou"` into `"haikou"=>"Haikou"`. Then you transform `citys["bj"] = {...};` into `"bj" => array(...);`

The regexes then are:

1. `(\w*?):("\w*?")`
2. `citys\[("\w*?")\]\s*=\s*{(.*?)}`

Comment: That's good ! Is it possible to solve this in one step by Regex? I think this is what I want. I'm sorry for my horrible expression.

Comment: Well, you can do it in one regex if you use recursive regexes in e.g. Ruby or CaptureCollection in .Net.

Comment: Appreciate your patient. Do you meant that it isn't possible to use recursive regexes in PHP ?

Comment: @Cynial Sorry, I was unclear. PHP/preg/PCRE do support recursive regexes. However, I don't recommend you to try that with this problem. I think (I haven't analyzed how that solution would be) that you can *match* with only one regex, but you will have supporting PHP code to do the *replace* part.

Answer (score 4):

```
json_decode('{"bj":"Beijing"}', true);
```

But for this function worked fine you need to have *proper* json, with keys also surrounded with quotes.

Comment: Thanks your answer， however I still hope to use Regex because I found there is a point of Regex in this case I can't understand.

Comment: Did you just say that you want to use a regex but don't know why? You have a json encoded string, just use json_decode.